# Java .split("|") not working

Tags: java, string, split

I just ran into the problem that the [split method](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split%28java.lang.String%29) for strings wouldn't work with character "|" as an argument. It somehow separates each character in the string.

Code:

```
String[] res = "12345|6".split("|");
Log.d("split", Arrays.toString(res));
```

Output:

```
split﹕ [, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, |, 6]
```

Comment: `split("\\|")`.

Comment: Note that `.split()` takes a regular expression and that `|` has special meaning in a regex.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Use escape character before | like below:

```
String[] res = "12345|6".split("\\|");
```

Similar "escape character logic" is required, when you are
dealing/splitting with any of the below special characters (used by
Regular Expression):

- OR sign (|)
- question mark (?)
- asterisk (*)
- plus sign (+)
- backslash (\)
- period (.)
- caret (^)
- square brackets ([ and ])
- dollar sign ($)
- ampersand (&)

Answer (score 6):

`|` is a regular expression key character and `split()` works with regualar expressions. Escape it like this: `\\|`

Answer (score 6):

You can try to escape it like this:

```
String[] res = "12345|6".split("\\|");
```

Pipe has special meaning in regular expression and it allows regular expression components to be logically ORed. So all you need to escape it using the `\\`

Answer (score 4):

If you have split using "||" then you use :

```
      yourstring.split(Pattern.quote("||"))
```

Comment: In fact, `quote` works for splitting on any literal (i.e. non-regex) string.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, simple and easy.

String[] res = "12345|6".split("[|]");

Answer (score -1):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String data = "12345|6|7|990";
    String[] arr = data.split("\\|");
    for(int i = 0 ; i< arr.length; i++){
      System.out.println(arr[i]);
    }
  }

O/p : 12345
6
7
990
```

Comment: Same answer as many previous.   And the demonstration code is unnecessary.