# How to convert a single address line into three address lines like Adress line 1,address line 2 ,address line 3 in java

Tags: java, arrays, string

I need to convert a single address line into three address lines in java

```
Address line - Wadgaon Shelke nagar ,Ganesh Garden Society ,A Building B B wing Flat no-3

Address line 1- Wadgaon Shelke nagar 
Address line 2- Ganesh Garden Society 
Address line 3 -A building B wing Flat no 3
```

Comment: According to what rule / logic? Maybe split at the `,`!?

Comment: You need to specify how to identify address line 1, 2 and 3. What differentiates them from each other?

Comment: how  if we store first address line after 3 spaces

Comment: Just use `string.split(" ,")`.  This will give you an array of strings which you can print in different lines.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer to this problem.

Use `split()` method to achieve your output.

I have changed the structure of your Address Line a little bit.

```
Address line - Wadgaon ,Shelke nagar |Ganesh Garden Society |A Building B B wing Flat no-3
```

Instead of separating your different addresses with `,` I am using another symbol `|`. You can use any other you want.

Now call `split()` method on this string. Let's call this string `adddressLine`.

```
String addressLine = Wadgaon ,Shelke nagar |Ganesh Garden Society |A Building B B wing Flat no-3;

String[] ans = addressLine.split("\\|");
For(String str : ans){
    System.out.println(str);
}
```

Here, I have basically *split* the `addressLine` string at points where I found `|` symbol.

Check out the answer I have mentioned below for why `addressLine.split("|")` won't work.

I Hope this helps.

[Check this answer for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32715552/java-split-not-working/32715599#:%7E:text=Use%20escape%20character%20before%20%7C%20like,used%20by%20Regular%20Expression%3A)